# How to download from Google Cloud Storage by Alpakka-gcs without providing secret-key?

Tags: scala, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, alpakka

I'm using [Alpakka-gcs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/google-cloud-storage.html) connecting to GCS from google-compute-engine perfectly if I provide gcs-secret-key on application.conf like the below.

```
alpakka.google.cloud.storage {
  project-id = "project_id"
  client-email = "client_email"
  private-key = "************gcs-secret-key************"
  base-url = "https://www.googleapis.com/" // default
  base-path = "/storage/v1" // default
  token-url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token" // default
  token-scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write" // default
}
```

My question is
how to connect compute-engine already having a credential without providing secret-key for alpakka.

The below code sample is working fine but I want to know alpakka way.

```scala
  def downloadObject(objectName:String, destFilePath: String): Unit = {

    import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId
    import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions
    import java.nio.file.Paths
    def credential:GoogleCredentials = ComputeEngineCredentials.create()
    val storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder.setCredentials(credential).setProjectId(projectId).build.getService

    val blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName))
    blob.downloadTo(Paths.get(destFilePath))
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the Alpakka sources, you can see an [accessToken creation](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/v2.0.2/google-cloud-storage/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/googlecloud/storage/impl/GoogleSession.scala). Sadly, this version only support the internal call to [GoogleTokenApi](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/d34dbc5bc75158bb51b7e51a466b2ceb3d2729e2/google-cloud-storage/src/main/scala/akka/stream/alpakka/googlecloud/storage/impl/GoogleTokenApi.scala#L39), a Alpakka made version to request token to Google Cloud. And based only on the private key, not on Metadata server or GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.

You can propose a change in the the project, or even develop it and push it to the project by using the Google Cloud oauth client library.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your detail explanation!